# Is it possible to show Google map view on Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Is it possible to show Google map view on Android Wear? I want to show a particular location to user on map.

Answer (score 3):

You may manage to embed a MapView in your activity, but **it won't work** as Android Wear does not have direct access to the network.

However, what you can do is **using the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)**.

1. Your Wear app should send a Message to your phone application
2. Your phone application downloads a bitmap of the map you want thanks to the static maps api
3. Your phone app sends back the image to the wear app
4. You show the bitmap in the wear application with an ImageView

The maps static API is quite powerful, and will allow you to do almost anything, including adding markers at the positions you want.

I have implemented such a system in an application, so I can guarantee you it'll work

Comment: hi, can you please help me with some sample to achieve this concept. i am new to static maps and android-wear

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that this is possible. Your host app on the mobile could generate a map picture and send it to the watch.
I think the same way the navigation preview on the watch is working.

Comment: Andre,   how to run navigation on mobile device from wear?